# ES 6 new syntax about const

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

Im new to ES6, certain things I know but still little bit confused about the following things, can anyone provide me some details about these new syntax:

Following are just sample snippet of code:

```
1. const { action, stage, conditions } = this.control.ajaxInfo;
```

What it is called exactly? What exactly this statement will do?, I tried this in console it executed without any error. But when I tried to trace those 3 constants, it shows undefined.

```
2. const getControlBindings = (control, context) => ({
    control,
    context,
    setAnswer,
    ajaxAction
  });
```

It is a function with some = and => notations, then what about this type of new syntax:

```
getControlBindings((control, context) => {
    control,
    context,
    setAnswer,
    ajaxAction
})
```

Then what is the main difference between these two type of functions? Please help me understating this.

Comment: [Destructuring](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=javascript&query=destructuring), [Arrow functions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/5007/arrow-functions#t=201702100709485870422)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** It means that your `this.control.ajaxInfo` object must contain properties with those names, which will be destructed into the variables in the left side.
For more see [**Destructing object in JS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
var controls = {
  action: 'a',
  stage: 'b',
  conditions: 'c',
}

const { action, stage, conditions } = controls;

console.log(action);
```

**2)** It is called [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They are also functions but with some nuances.

```
const getControlBindings = (control, context) => ({
    control,
    context,
    setAnswer,
    ajaxAction
  });
```

This is a function, which accept parameters control and context and returns an object with shape

```
{
   control,
   context,
   setAnswer,
   ajaxAction
}
```

Everythinig after `=>` is the body of arrow function. You can add to arrow function a bracket body with

```
 const getControlBindings = (control, context) => { return ({
        control,
        context,
        setAnswer,
        ajaxAction
      }); };
```

And if you add brackets body, you need to use `return` statement explicitly, if not added brackets body, you must write a single statement which will be returned from the function.

Comment: Thanks @Suren Srapyan, wow nice explanation, it means : 1. this syntax creates 3 constants from one object, is it right? 2. this syntax creates constant object.

Comment: 1) yes, 2) no, it does not create const object, but it creates const `getControlBindings` function, so it can't refer to another function anymore. it is attached to the current function.The returned object will not be const

Comment: I was little bit confused, now i got it. Thanks @Suren Srapyan.

Comment: 2) They are not called *lambda* anywhere in Javascript. They are **arrow functions**.

Answer (score 3):

1. Is the example of Object destructing in ES2016/ES6. In this, 3 separate const with the values of the parameter with the same name mentioned in the left hand side of the equals. i.e. action, stage, condition.

   ```
   var controls = {
       action: 'GET',
       stage: 'Test'
   }

   const { action, stage} = controls;

   console.log(action) // Outputs GET
   ```
2. Is the example of arrow function. In the first case u are create an arrow function getControllsBinding which takes control and context parameters and returns an object with

   ```
   {control,
    context,
    setAnswer,
    ajaxAction }
   ```

The other definition is like your passing the arrow function as a parameter to getControllsBinding function. Note there is slight syntax problem in this you need to wrap the

```
    {control,
     context,
     setAnswer,
     ajaxAction }
```

withing parenthesis like below

```
    ({control,
     context,
     setAnswer,
     ajaxAction })
```

Below are the some good material to start with ES2015/ES6

Arrow functions : https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-arrow-functions

Object Destructing : https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-object-destructuring

Answer (score 0):

Found a good [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for you. Hope it helps.

One more on [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)